# Makefile to compile 2 applications in C

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to use the Makefile to compile source codes into 2 executable applications.

How do I properly compile two executable applications at once using a single Makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both source files are being included in both versions of the executable, which means that there are two separate instances of main.

Replace line:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJ_EXE) $(LIBRARY)
```

with

```
%: %00.o $(LIBRARY)
```

This will ensure that only `client00.o` is used to build `client` and `server00.o` is used to build `server`.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Good call.  Fixed the extensions and name.

Comment: Also, you should not add `LDFLAGS` to the compile line (the command in `.c.o`).  `LDFLAGS` contains link-time flags and should only be in the link command.